# Error while running SQL server nested UPDATE query

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have tried looking for answer in the forum but couldnt find any which could help me.

My situation is that I have 2 tables, and email in one table has to be updated with respect to ids from another table.

My problem is I am trying to run an Update query, and getting this error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,
>
> > , >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I realize why I am getting this error, but I am not able to simplify my query. Can any1 help?

```
UPDATE A
SET    Email = (SELECT B.[Email Address]
                FROM   B
                WHERE  B.ID IN (SELECT ID
                                FROM   A
                                WHERE  Email LIKE 'abc@def.ghi'))
WHERE  A.ID IN (SELECT ID
                FROM   A
                WHERE  Email LIKE 'abc@def.ghi')
```

Could anyone suggest me how to proceed?

Comment: The sub query is returning more than one value. You could try adding `DISTINCT` but that will only work if all the values are the same. If they aren't which email address should it use?

Comment: I have a set of emails over written by "abc@def.ghi" in the table A which I need to update with emails from table B if email abc@def.ghi is the email in table A. and this is the best i could come up with. I am new to sql queries. any help or any direction of thought would be appreciated. there are around 300 email ids with the address abc@def.ghi in table A.

Comment: Thank you martin for the suggestion. I will keep it in mind for future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what table structure you have and what exactly do you want to achieve.

If I guess correctly, you could try something like this:

```
UPDATE A SET Email = (SELECT [Email Address] FROM B WHERE B.ID = A.ID)
WHERE Email = 'abc@def.ghi';
```

Is this what you wanted (that is, to set A's email field to be equal to the B's [Email Address] from B that matches A's ID)?

Comment: Thanks Seramme, It looks like the solution I have been looking for. And thanks for correcting my mistake. Thank you all for helping me out in such a short time.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, I think you could something like below:

```
 UPDATE AAlias
 SET
    Email = AAlias.EmailAdd
 FROM
     A AAlias
 INNER JOIN B AAlias
     ON AAlias.ID = BAlias.ID AND A.Email LIKE 'BLAH BLAH'
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you for the response praveen, but this is not what i was looking for exactly.